# Page refresh issue in angular showing cannot GET / {page name}

Tags: angular, laravel

My application is based on angular js (Front) and laravel (backend api) . I removed # from url . It is working fine when i click on any link . But when i reload page it is giving error e.g

> url : http://localhost:9000/users  can Cannot GET /users and in
>   network it is showing
>
> .
>
> Request URL: http://localhost:9000/users 
>  Request Method: GET 
>   Status Code: 404 Not Found
>  Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:9000 
>   Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

[image]

Comment: Please use the text formatting features.

Comment: you can read more about https://stackoverflow.com/a/47369761/5452941

Comment: Possible duplicate of [404 Error on refresh for angular(v4+) deployed on tomcat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47366792/404-error-on-refresh-for-angularv4-deployed-on-tomcat-server)

Answer (score 2):

This is related to the routing system. If you use *HTML 5* routing, you need to configure this in your web server.

If you don't want to configure this, you need to re-add `#` to your urls, to let javascript preserve your `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 routing, you should config your nginx `try_files` config. It maybe looks like that:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

More official details about server configuration is [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration)