# Angular redirect after login -> 404

Tags: angular, tomcat

After a user is logged in, he will be redirected depending on his role/s.

When I login with role MANAGER or ADMIN I will be correctly redirected. However, when I login with role USER I get a 404 from Tomcat. The URL he tries to access is localhost:8080/myApp/usr, which is correct.

When I navigate with role USER to localhost:8080/myApp (the redirect page for role MANAGER or ADMIN) and then go manually to localhost:8080/myApp/usr via a button it works.

The problem does not occur within my IDE but only if I deploy it on a tomcat.
I appreciate any hint or help.

**app-routing.modul.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'usr', component: UsrComponent }
];
```

**app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.isLoggedIn = !!this.tokenStorageService.getToken();

  if (!this.isLoggedIn) {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
onLogin() {
...
if (this.roles.includes('ROLE_MANAGER') || this.roles.includes('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  } else {
    this.router.navigate(['/usr']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Route `'/login'` is not defined........

Comment: Just missed to paste, thanks.

Comment: Ah, so that's not the problem. Then I don't know, because everything seems in order :/

Comment: This solved my issue: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47369761/4890818)

Comment: Aaah, very nice